# Wrap the function into another function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I have the code that sorts an array of objects by the object property using lodash. It’s pretty simple:

```
_.sortBy(data.cycles, "id");
```

However, I discovered that `data.cycles[].id` might be a string, so I have to convert each property to number before passing it to `_.sortBy`. Is there any elegant way of doing it? I think I should combine `_.property` and `parseInt` somehow, but I don’t know how.

`data.cycles` might look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "20",
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "name": "Sarah"
  },
  {
    "id": "158",
    "name": "Bill"
  },
  {
    "id": "-6",
    "name": "Jack"
  },
  {
    "id": "59",
    "name": "Bob"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would compose a [sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) callback as follows:

```
var collection = [
    { id: '20', name: 'John' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Sarah' },
    { id: 158, name: 'Bill' },
    { id: '-6', name: 'Jack' },
    { id: 59, name: 'Bob' }
];

_.sortBy(collection, _.flow(_.property('id'), parseInt));
// →
// [
//   { id: '-6', name: 'Jack' },
//   { id: 15, name: 'Sarah' },
//   { id: '20', name: 'John' },
//   { id: 59, name: 'Bob' },
//   { id: 158, name: 'Bill' }
// ]
```

The [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs#flow) function is useful when you want to compose a callback function out of many functions, it just forwards the output to the next function in line. The [property()](https://lodash.com/docs#property) function returns a function that gets the specified property name from it's argument. This is the `id`, and that gets passed to `parseInt()`.

We're essentially mapping and sorting at the same time. This has an efficiency advantage, in addition to being a one-liner: it doesn't have to iterate over the whole collection twice. This isn't a big deal with smaller collections, but with larger collections, the impact is noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to run [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) first and modify `id`, then do a sort.

In vanilla JS, it would look something like:

```
function mapFn(item){
  item.id = parseInt(item.id, 10);
  return item;
}

var sortedCycles = data.cycles.map(mapFn).sort(sortFn);
```

In lodash, you could have:

```
var sortedCycles = _.sortBy(_.map(data.cycles, mapFn), 'id');
// or
var sortedCycles = _.chain(data.cycles).map(mapFn).sortBy('id').value()
```

Comment: Yes, this way or another way: `_.sortBy(data.cycles, (cycle) => parseInt(cycle.id));` But I hope there’s a completely lodash solution.

Comment: @gxoptg Lodash actually has a map function (it's a link in the post). You can do something like `_.sortBy(_.map(data.cycles, mapFn), 'id');` or probably use `chain` like `_.chain(data.cycles).map(mapFn).sort('id').value()`.